# Style controls in Silverlight - global

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Is there any way to create "global" styles for all TextBoxes used in application? So I don't have to do Template=... on each TextBox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to use an implicit style.

Declare the style as normal:

```
<Style x:Key="MyDefaultStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    ....
</Style>
```

Then declare:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="MyDefaultStyle />
```

The important part is that you are missing the `x:Key` declaration. This will get applied to all TextBoxes in your application that don't explicitly set a `Style`. Include this in a global resource file.

There's [more information](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Implicit-Styles-in-Silverlight-4.aspx) on SilverlightShow.net.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also have Controls.dll with my own custom controls and generic.xaml. Is there any way to put those styles into this generic.xaml? It seems that I use lot of custom controls and lot of built-on controls. Would be natural to place all styles there. Or maybe I should wrap TextBox and other stock controls into my own controls and then I will achieve one common place for styles?

Comment: @katit - I *think* you can put them in generic.xaml. We have them in a file called "ImplicitStyles.xaml" which is in (what sounds like) the equivalent of your controls.dll. I've not got the code here to double check how it's organised so I'm working from memory.