# wpf canvas add element from resources

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new to wpf

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Ellipse x:Key="connectorNode" Height="20" Width="20" Fill="Green" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" MouseMove="Ellipse_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonDown="Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonUp"></Ellipse>
 </Window.Resources>
```

How can i add an instance of the Ellipse in the resources to a canvas, i only want to specify `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Right` but use the same property values as in resources

```
<Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Do you want to do this in xaml or in code?

Comment: @Djerry i already did it in code, but i also need to do it in xaml for testing

Comment: You will usually not use any UI elements as resources. What are you trying to achieve? Note that you couldn't even add that Ellipse to more than one Panel at the same time.

Comment: What you might do is create a style and apply that to Ellipses you are adding.

Comment: @Djerry right style seems like what i need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to create a generic style and apply it to every Ellipse added, this is how you can do it:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="EllipseStyle" TargetType="Ellipse">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
            <EventSetter Event="Control.MouseMove" Handler="Control_MouseMove" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource EllipseStyle}" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Edit: I've added "EventSetter" so your events can be defined in the style (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001619/add-code-to-a-style-in-wpf)).

Comment: You can not set Event Handlers like `MouseMove` this way.

Comment: @NovitchiS i figured, i will have to add them to each instance

Comment: @NovitchiS Ever heard about `EventSetter`?

Comment: @Clemens: nice timing, just updated my answer to include that!

Comment: @Clemens I forgot about it, never really had the need to use them.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use an element from resources and apply only canvas properties you can do it this way:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="connectorNode" >
        <Ellipse 
            Height="20" 
            Width="20" 
            Fill="Green" 
            Stroke="Black" 
            StrokeThickness="2" 
            MouseMove="Ellipse_MouseMove" 
            MouseLeftButtonDown="Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
            MouseLeftButtonUp="Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonUp" />
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Canvas>
    <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource connectorNode}"/>
    <ContentControl Canvas.Left="50" Template="{StaticResource connectorNode}"/>
</Canvas>
```